# IOCP Socket Worker threads works too much slow when i test it with client simulator

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client, iocp

I'm developing a mmorpg with iocp sockets.When im testing with my client simulator , after 70-80 connection , writing operation at socket worker thread slowing down than users get lagged.

This is my worker thread ;

```
typedef void(*OperationHandler)(Socket * s, uint32 len);

void HandleReadComplete(Socket * s, uint32 len);
void HandleWriteComplete(Socket * s, uint32 len);
void HandleShutdown(Socket * s, uint32 len);

static OperationHandler ophandlers[] =
{
    &HandleReadComplete,
    &HandleWriteComplete,
    &HandleShutdown
};

uint32 THREADCALL SocketMgr::SocketWorkerThread(void * lpParam){
SocketMgr *socketMgr = (SocketMgr *)lpParam;
HANDLE cp = socketMgr->GetCompletionPort();
DWORD len;
Socket * s = nullptr;
OverlappedStruct * ov = nullptr;
LPOVERLAPPED ol_ptr;

while (socketMgr->m_bWorkerThreadsActive)
{
    if (!GetQueuedCompletionStatus(cp, &len, (LPDWORD)&s, &ol_ptr, INFINITE))
    {
        if (s != nullptr)
            s->Disconnect();
        continue;
    }

    ov = CONTAINING_RECORD(ol_ptr, OverlappedStruct, m_overlap);
    if (ov->m_event == SOCKET_IO_THREAD_SHUTDOWN)
    {
        delete ov;
        return 0;
    }

        if (ov->m_event < NUM_SOCKET_IO_EVENTS)
            ophandlers[ov->m_event](s, len);

}

return 0;}
```

This is Write Complete event handler;

```
    void HandleWriteComplete(Socket * s, uint32 len)
{
    if (s->IsDeleted()) {
        return;
    }

    s->m_writeEvent.Unmark();
    s->BurstBegin();                    // Lock
    s->GetWriteBuffer().Remove(len);
    TRACE("SOCK = %d removed = %d",s->GetFd(),len);
    if (s->GetWriteBuffer().GetContiguousBytes() > 0) {
        s->WriteCallback();
    }
    else {
        s->DecSendLock();
    }
    s->BurstEnd();                    // Unlock
}
```

WriteCallBack function ;

```
    void Socket::WriteCallback()
{
    if (IsDeleted() || !IsConnected()) {
        return;
    }

    // We don't want any writes going on while this is happening.
    Guard lock(m_writeMutex);
    if(writeBuffer.GetContiguousBytes())
    {
        DWORD w_length = 0;
        DWORD flags = 0;

        // attempt to push all the data out in a non-blocking fashion.
        WSABUF buf;
        buf.len = (ULONG)writeBuffer.GetContiguousBytes();
        buf.buf = (char*)writeBuffer.GetBufferStart();

        
        m_writeEvent.Mark();
        m_writeEvent.Reset(SOCKET_IO_EVENT_WRITE_END);

        TRACE("\n SOCK = %d aslında giden = %X THREADID = %d", GetFd(), buf.buf[4],GetCurrentThreadId());
        int r = WSASend(m_fd, &buf, 1, &w_length, flags, &m_writeEvent.m_overlap, 0);
        if (r == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING)
        {
            m_writeEvent.Unmark();
            DecSendLock();
            Disconnect();
        }

        
    }
    else
    {
        // Write operation is completed.
        
        DecSendLock();
    }
}
```

this is stuffs about mutexes ;

```
public:
    /* Atomic wrapper functions for increasing read/write locks */
    INLINE void IncSendLock() { Guard lock(m_writeMutex); ++m_writeLock; }
    INLINE void DecSendLock() { Guard lock(m_writeMutex); 
    --m_writeLock; }
    INLINE bool HasSendLock() {Guard lock(m_writeMutex); return (m_writeLock != 0); }
    INLINE bool AcquireSendLock()
    {
        Guard lock(m_writeMutex);
        if (m_writeLock != 0)
            return false;
        ++m_writeLock;
        return true;
    }
private:
    // Write lock, stops multiple write events from being posted.
    uint32 m_writeLock;
    std::recursive_mutex m_writeLockMutex;
```

This is read event handler;

```
    void HandleReadComplete(Socket * s, uint32 len)
{
    if (s->IsDeleted())
        return;

    s->m_readEvent.Unmark();
    if (len)
    {
        s->GetReadBuffer().IncrementWritten(len);
        s->OnRead();
        s->SetupReadEvent();
    }
    else
    {
        // s->Delete();   // Queue deletion.
        s->Disconnect();
    }
}
```

OnRead function ;

```
void KOSocket::OnRead()
{
    Packet pkt;

    for (;;)
    {
        

        if (m_remaining == 0)
        {
            if (GetReadBuffer().GetSize() < 5) {
                //TRACE("pkt returnzzz GetFd %d", GetFd());
                return; //check for opcode as well
            }


            uint16 header = 0;
            GetReadBuffer().Read(&header, 2);
            //printf("header : %X", header);//derle at k
            if (header != 0x55AA)
            {
                TRACE("%s: Got packet without header 0x55AA, got 0x%X\n", GetRemoteIP().c_str(), header);
                goto error_handler;
            }

            GetReadBuffer().Read(&m_remaining, 2);
            if (m_remaining == 0)
            {
                TRACE("%s: Got packet without an opcode, this should never happen.\n", GetRemoteIP().c_str());
                goto error_handler;
            }
        }

        if (m_remaining > GetReadBuffer().GetAllocatedSize())
        {
            TRACE("%s: Packet received which was %u bytes in size, maximum of %u.\n", GetRemoteIP().c_str(), m_remaining, GetReadBuffer().GetAllocatedSize());
            goto error_handler;
        }

        if (m_remaining > GetReadBuffer().GetSize())
        {
            if (m_readTries > 4)
            {
                TRACE("%s: packet fragmentation count is over 4, disconnecting as they're probably up to something bad\n", GetRemoteIP().c_str());
                goto error_handler;
            }
            m_readTries++;
            return;
        }

        uint8 *in_stream = new uint8[m_remaining];

        m_readTries = 0;
        GetReadBuffer().Read(in_stream, m_remaining);

        uint16 footer = 0;
        GetReadBuffer().Read(&footer, 2);

        

        if (footer != 0xAA55
            || !DecryptPacket(in_stream, pkt))
        {
            TRACE("%s: Footer invalid (%X) or failed to decrypt.\n", GetRemoteIP().c_str(), footer);
            delete [] in_stream;
            goto error_handler;
        }

        delete [] in_stream;

        // Update the time of the last (valid) response from the client.
        m_lastResponse = UNIXTIME2;

        //TRACE("pkt:%d GetFd %d", pkt.GetOpcode(), GetFd());
        if (!HandlePacket(pkt))
        {
            TRACE("%s: Handler for packet %X returned false\n", GetRemoteIP().c_str(), pkt.GetOpcode());
#ifndef _DEBUG
            goto error_handler;
#endif
        }

        m_remaining = 0;
        
    }
    //TRACE("pkt return11 GetFd %d", GetFd());
    return;

error_handler:
    Disconnect();
}
```

and this is how my server sends to packet to clients ;

```
BurstBegin();
//TRACE("\n SOCK = %d FREE SPACE = %d ",GetFd(),GetWriteBuffer().GetSpace()/*, GetWriteBuffer().m_writeLock*/);
if (GetWriteBuffer().GetSpace() < size_t(len + 6))
{
    size_t freespace = GetWriteBuffer().GetSpace();
    BurstEnd();
    Disconnect();
    return false;
}
TRACE("\n SOCK = %d gitmesi gereken paket = %X THREADID = %d", GetFd(), out_stream[0],GetCurrentThreadId());
r = BurstSend((const uint8*)"\xaa\x55", 2);
if (r) r = BurstSend((const uint8*)&len, 2);
if (r) r = BurstSend((const uint8*)out_stream, len);
if (r) r = BurstSend((const uint8*)"\x55\xaa", 2);
if (r) BurstPush();
BurstEnd();
```

The number of Worker threads according to processor number;

```
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkerThreads; i++)
{
m_thread[i] = new Thread(SocketWorkerThread, this);
}
```

The server which i tested on it has Intel XEON E5-2630 v3 2.40 ghz (2 processor)

Can you guys help me about how can i improve performance ? For ex: when the client moves in the map per 1.5 second that sends to move packet to server and if it success server sends to every client in that region that move packet.

When client count increasing server starts to slow down to send back to packets to clients.My write buffer filling fully (it's capacity 16384 bytes) cause server couldn't send packets inside of the writebuffer.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service. Please reduce your example to a [mcve] (emphasis on "minimal") that reproduces the same issue.